# Как прокрутить объекты вместе с RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, list

Можно ли прокрутить вместе с списком RecyclerView, объекты которые выше его?

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/quizLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/flagImageView"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img1"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:border_width="3dp"
            app:border_color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@+id/quizLinearLayout"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="85dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

        `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` здесь не работает
```

Comment: Думаю в вашем случае у вас не получиться,как вариант вам можно в адаптере  разные типы view выводить

Comment: засунуть всё в scrollview